# Join data frames with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two data frames **df1** and **df2**. Both of their number of coloumns and rows are different. But they have one common column called **LAC**. I need to join these two dataframes together. I tried this `"new_df = df1.join(df2, on=['LAC'], how='left_outer')"` But it gave me errors. Please give me correct answers!!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a question on stackoverflow. Please write which errors you get and please provide a little reproducible example of your df1 and df2.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join